# python: calculating exponential moving average

Tags: python, pandas, average, exponential

While calculating a simple moving average is as simple as the following:

```
MAs = closes.rolling(window=MAsWin).mean()
```

I cannot really find out how to calculate the exponential moving average. I tried many variations of the following but without luck:

```
MAs = closes.rolling(window= MAsWin, win_type='exponential').mean(std=0.1)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.ewm`:

```py
MAs = closes.ewm(span=MAsWin, adjust=False).mean()
```

Ref https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Answer (score 1):

I used pandas to calculate EMA. Here is the documentation of EMA function in pandas library
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html
And down below there is a similar problem, hope it helps You a bit
[calculate exponential moving average in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488670/calculate-exponential-moving-average-in-python)