# EMA calculation in python

Tags: python, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I want to calculate ema in python. I searched on google a lot of functions are available. But I want to calculate ema with single value not serie values. I did it with pine script on tradingview here is my pinescript code:

```py
dd = lowest (low, 4)//get lowest value in 4 series

yy = highest (high, 5)//get highest value in 5 series

diff = yy - dd

ortdiff = ema(ema(diff,3),3)
```

How can ı calculate ema of single values? Any library pr any function for calculate ema?
Thanks

ema calculations on pinescripts:

pine_ema(src, length) =>

```
alpha = 2 / (length + 1)

sum = 0.0

sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])
```

How can I calculate these functions on python?

Comment: I might've misunderstood your question, but what do you mean by calculating an EMA of a single value? What do you expect to get in return? In any case, if you're working with series (which it seems you are, given your Pine code), I suggest working with pandas library for python, it's the library to work with on timeseries data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488670/calculate-exponential-moving-average-in-python

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment @CrispyHoliday I want to calculate my code emas. for example ema(3.12,3) //3.12 ema value to be calculated, 3 period

Comment: The `ema` of a single value is that value.  The `ema` is an average, and the average of the set `[x]` is `x`.

Comment: Tradingview calculate pinescript code on my questions. 

pine_ema(src, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

How can I calculate these functions on python?